# Stop Flask from automatically escaping percent-encoding in URLs?

Tags: python, flask

If I `curl -vvv 'http://localhost:8080/video/RIHANNA%3A-FENTY-BEAUTY-%2D-Review-%2B-First-Impressions?v=N_zDcuX1Y54'` then I get a  `request.full_path` of `/video/RIHANNA:-FENTY-BEAUTY---Review-+-First-Impressions?v=N_zDcuX1Y54`.
The problem is the `-%2D-` bit being trampled down to `---` because I make an important distinction between a dash and its percent-encoded counterpart.  Is there any more raw form of the `request.full_path` that I can access?

Comment: *“because I make an important distinction between a dash and its percent-encoded counterpart”* Well, don’t. *Browsers* will decode this before making the request.

Comment: @Ry︁ ah of course. Thank you.